# inject factory data into controller angular.js

Tags: angularjs, factory

I am a beginner in angular and dont know how to call `factory` into `controller`. Please check my code below. I dont know this is a right way or not. please guide

**HTML**

```
<div class="cart" ng-controller="cartWatch">
        <table width="100%">
            <tr ng-repeat="pro in item">
                <td>Name : {{pro.title}}</td>
                <td>Quantity : {{pro.quantity}} <input type="text" ng-model="pro.quantity"></input></td>
                <td>Price : {{pro.price | currency : '&#8377'}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="total">
            total Price : <strong>{{totalPrice()}}</strong> <br>
            Discount : <strong>{{bill.discount}}</strong> <br>
            You Pay : <strong>{{subTotal()}}</strong>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var appProduct = angular.module('myProduct', []);

appProduct.factory('Items', function() {
 var items = {};
 items.query = function() {

 return [
    {title: 'Paint pots', quantity: 8, price: 3.95},
    {title: 'Polka dots', quantity: 17, price: 12.95},
    {title: 'Pebbles', quantity: 5, price: 6.95}
 ];
 };
 return items;
});

appProduct.controller('cartWatch', function($scope, Items){ 

    $scope.bill = {};
    $scope.totalBeforeDiscount = {};




    $scope.totalPrice = function(){
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i <= $scope.item.length - 1; i++) {
            total +=   $scope.item[i].price * $scope.item[i].quantity;
        }
        return total;
    }
})
```

Above code gave following eror in console

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at $scope.totalPrice (controller.js:105)
    at n.$digest (angular.min.js:142)
    at n.$apply (angular.min.js:145)
    at angular.min.js:21
    at Object.invoke (angular.min.js:41)
    at c (angular.min.js:21)
    at yc (angular.min.js:21)
    at ee (angular.min.js:20)
    at angular.min.js:313
```

Comment: what is the issue ?

Comment: @Sajeetharan please check updated question .. it gave following error in console 

------------------------------------------------------

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at $scope.totalPrice (controller.js:105)
    at n.$digest (angular.min.js:142)
    at n.$apply (angular.min.js:145)
    at angular.min.js:21
    at Object.invoke (angular.min.js:41)
    at c (angular.min.js:21)
    at yc (angular.min.js:21)
    at ee (angular.min.js:20)
    at angular.min.js:313

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you are missing, you are never consuming your method from your factory, and you are not considering the items which returned by factory in your controller's method.

**Factory:**

```
 appProduct.factory('Items', function() {
   var items = {};
   return {
     query: function() {
       return [{
         title: 'Paint pots',
         quantity: 8,
         price: 3.95
       }, {
         title: 'Polka dots',
         quantity: 17,
         price: 12.95
       }, {
         title: 'Pebbles',
         quantity: 5,
         price: 6.95
       }];
     }
   }    
 });
```

**Controller:**

```
appProduct.controller('cartWatch', function($scope, Items){ 
    $scope.items = Items.query();
    $scope.bill = {};
    $scope.totalBeforeDiscount = {};
    $scope.totalPrice = function(){
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i <= $scope.items.length - 1; i++) {
            total +=   $scope.items[i].price * $scope.items[i].quantity;
        }
        $scope.totalBeforeDiscount =total;
    }
})
```

Here is the working [`Plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/WKyZrkarhos4cArosvam?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
var appProduct = angular.module('myProduct', []);

appProduct.factory('Items', function() {
 var items = {};
 items.query = function() {

 return [
    {title: 'Paint pots', quantity: 8, price: 3.95},
    {title: 'Polka dots', quantity: 17, price: 12.95},
    {title: 'Pebbles', quantity: 5, price: 6.95}
 ];
 };
 return items.query;
});

appProduct.controller('cartWatch', ['$scope', '$Items', function ($scope, Items) {
    $scope.bill = {};
    $scope.totalBeforeDiscount = {};

    $scope.totalPrice = function(){
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i <= $scope.items.length - 1; i++) {
            total +=   $scope.items[i].price * $scope.item[i].quantity;
        }
        return total;
    }
}]);
```